# get the current zoom of the google map in react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

How do I get the current zoom in react-google-maps?

Here is my code:

```
<GoogleMap
    center={center}
    zoom={zoom}
    zoomControl={true}
    ref={mapRef}
    id="example-map"
    onLoad={(map) => {
      setMap(map);
    }}
    onZoomChanged={() => {
      setZoom(
       ????????
      );
    }}
  >
```

Comment: So you want to **get** the zoom, and tried `setZoom()`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this first by getting the google.maps.Map object by using React refs. In the code snippet below you will see that I added a ref inside the `<GoogleMap/>` then put the map to `this.mapObject`.

```
  <GoogleMap
        ref={(map) => this.mapObject = map}
        defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
        defaultCenter={this.state.center}
        onZoomChanged = {this.zoomChange}
      />
```

Then in onZoomChanged, you will use `this.mapObject.getZoom()` to get the current zoom level of your map. Here's a working [code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/getting-map-object-and-onzoomchange-fspbal?file=data.json) and a code snippet below. *Note: Use your own API key in the `index.js` file in the sample code to make it work.*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, } from "react-google-maps";

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: { lat: 6.8667528, lng: 79.8769134 }
    };
  }

  zoomChange = () => {
    console.log("Zoom changed");
    console.log(this.mapObject.getZoom());
  };

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        ref={map => (this.mapObject = map)}
        defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
        defaultCenter={this.state.center}
        onZoomChanged={this.zoomChange}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: "500px" }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```